# SAI in STM32F4 behaves strange

Tags: stm32, audio-codec

So I'm trying to connect CS4270 codec to STM32F446RE. I managed to drive DAC part using SAI sublock B, but when I enable sublock A for receiving the sent data becomes corrupted (instead of L R L R on data line I get L R 0 0 L R 0 0).

I wanted to verify if analog section works but enabling digital loopback returns noise. When I hook up logic analyzer to data output it indeed shows that there's byte swap in ADC datastream.

Below is the code of SAI initialization. When commented part gets uncommented the described issue is generated.

The code is more or a less cubeMX output as I hoped it would work out of the box.

```
static void MX_SAI1_Init(void)
{
    hsai_BlockA1.Instance = SAI1_Block_A;
    hsai_BlockA1.Init.Protocol = SAI_FREE_PROTOCOL;
    hsai_BlockA1.Init.AudioMode = SAI_MODESLAVE_RX;
    hsai_BlockA1.Init.DataSize = SAI_DATASIZE_16;
    hsai_BlockA1.Init.FirstBit = SAI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
    hsai_BlockA1.Init.ClockStrobing = SAI_CLOCKSTROBING_FALLINGEDGE;
    hsai_BlockA1.Init.Synchro = SAI_SYNCHRONOUS;
    hsai_BlockA1.Init.OutputDrive = SAI_OUTPUTDRIVE_DISABLE;
    hsai_BlockA1.Init.FIFOThreshold = SAI_FIFOTHRESHOLD_EMPTY;
    hsai_BlockA1.Init.SynchroExt = SAI_SYNCEXT_DISABLE;
    hsai_BlockA1.Init.MonoStereoMode = SAI_STEREOMODE;
    hsai_BlockA1.Init.CompandingMode = SAI_NOCOMPANDING;
    hsai_BlockA1.Init.TriState = SAI_OUTPUT_NOTRELEASED;
    hsai_BlockA1.FrameInit.FrameLength = 32;
    hsai_BlockA1.FrameInit.ActiveFrameLength = 16;
    hsai_BlockA1.FrameInit.FSDefinition = SAI_FS_STARTFRAME;
    hsai_BlockA1.FrameInit.FSPolarity = SAI_FS_ACTIVE_LOW;
    hsai_BlockA1.FrameInit.FSOffset = SAI_FS_FIRSTBIT;
    hsai_BlockA1.SlotInit.FirstBitOffset = 0;
    hsai_BlockA1.SlotInit.SlotSize = SAI_SLOTSIZE_DATASIZE;
    hsai_BlockA1.SlotInit.SlotNumber = 1;
    hsai_BlockA1.SlotInit.SlotActive = 0x00000000;
    /*if (HAL_SAI_InitProtocol(&hsai_BlockA1, SAI_I2S_MSBJUSTIFIED, SAI_PROTOCOL_DATASIZE_16BIT, 2) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }*/
  hsai_BlockB1.Instance = SAI1_Block_B;
  hsai_BlockB1.Init.AudioMode = SAI_MODEMASTER_TX;
  hsai_BlockB1.Init.Synchro = SAI_ASYNCHRONOUS;
  hsai_BlockB1.Init.OutputDrive = SAI_OUTPUTDRIVE_ENABLE;
  hsai_BlockB1.Init.NoDivider = SAI_MASTERDIVIDER_ENABLE;
  hsai_BlockB1.Init.FIFOThreshold = SAI_FIFOTHRESHOLD_EMPTY;
  hsai_BlockB1.Init.ClockSource = SAI_CLKSOURCE_NA;
  hsai_BlockB1.Init.AudioFrequency = SAI_AUDIO_FREQUENCY_MCKDIV;
  hsai_BlockB1.Init.Mckdiv = 7;
  hsai_BlockB1.Init.SynchroExt = SAI_SYNCEXT_DISABLE;
  hsai_BlockB1.Init.MonoStereoMode = SAI_STEREOMODE;
  hsai_BlockB1.Init.CompandingMode = SAI_NOCOMPANDING;
  hsai_BlockB1.Init.TriState = SAI_OUTPUT_NOTRELEASED;
  if (HAL_SAI_InitProtocol(&hsai_BlockB1, SAI_I2S_MSBJUSTIFIED, SAI_PROTOCOL_DATASIZE_16BIT, 2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SAI1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SAI1_Init 2 */

}
```

What's wrong with my initialization code, how can I get SAI to receive & transmit I2S data at the same time?
Also why are the bytes swapped?

EDIT
my cubemx config
[image: my cubemx config]

Comment: Do you have a Nucleo board? If so, the UART connection going to the ST-Link conflicts with SAI module A.

Comment: Yes, I do have nucleo board and I'm using UART. could you show me where the conflict is? As cubemx allowed me to configure it without any problem. GPIOB2 which is SAI modules A's data pin doesn't collide with uart

Comment: If there's a conflict it's on PA3. But I might have been mistaken. It's not used if the SAI1 block A is in synchronous mode. But then again, I'm unsure how block A is synchronized. Can you provide a schematic or at least a table of how the MCU is connected to the CS4270 or to itself (loopback)?

Comment: I updated my post. yes. SAI block A is synchronised to block B internally so in theory only the data pin is needed

Comment: I played around with the code a bit and now I get 3 samples at the output, 2 zeros, repeat